# queryIntentActivities() includes private Activity in results

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've an Activity in one of my apps that has an Intent filter, but is still marked as private, i.e. `android:exported=false`:

```
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name=".facebook.PostToFacebookActivity" android:icon="@drawable/facebook_icon" android:label="@string/facebook_built_in">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

(The Activity is for internal use only; part of my app allows the user to choose from a list of all Activities that can send text somewhere, and this allows me to add a couple of app-internal options to the overall list easily.)

However, when I use `queryIntentActivites()` from a *different* app, my "private" activity is still returned:

```
// Returned list includes the above activity, even though it's declared private.
List<ResolveInfo> infoList = pm.queryIntentActivities(
        myIntent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY | 
        PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS
);
```

The basic *security* seems to work fine, as if I try to start the Activity from the other app, I get a security exception. But it seems odd that asking for Activities for an Intent would give you a list including Activities that you're not allowed to start.

I'd have thought that if an Activity was set not to export, it wouldn't even appear in the `queryIntentActivities()` results. That's the behaviour I want, anyway. Is there a flag I can use to say "don't show me private Activities", or an easy way of filtering the results to get rid of Activities I'm not allowed to start?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'd have thought that if an Activity was set not to export, it wouldn't even appear in the queryIntentActivities() results.

That's *way* too logical. :-)

> Is there a flag I can use to say "don't show me private Activities"

Certainly none that are documented.

> or an easy way of filtering the results to get rid of Activities I'm not allowed to start?

Given a `ResolveInfo`, the `activityInfo.exported` `boolean` should be false for non-exported activities. You could loop through your `queryIntentActivities()` results and weed out the non-exported ones.

Comment: I've absolutely no idea why I didn't mark this as the answer two years ago! Remedied.

Comment: @MattGibson Funnily enough, without seeing this post I also just wrote an activity to post to FB from my app via this "cheat". Came across the same problem as you did. Other apps are finding mine. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @theblitz Nope; in the end I never actually needed to solve this problem from the perspective of a third party app trying to use mine, so I didn't investigate. I'd probably just ask a new SO question, if you've not already done that...

Comment: @MattGibson I also needed from the perspective of someone else.
I left it at "their problem not mine".

Howeve, I also opened a bug for it on Google's Android M bug report.